# If I use a raw socket on Linux, will incoming packets with bad TCP checksums be dropped by the kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, raw-sockets

Right now I'm writing a program that uses a raw TCP socket.  If there are any incoming packets with bad TCP checksums, will the kernel pass them to the program or drop them?  The reason I want to know is to figure out if I'll need to manually do that check or not.

Comment: Why are you messing with raw sockets?

Comment: So are you handling TCP by yourself or are you letting the the api/kernel handle tcp?

Comment: @tjameson: Yes, I'm using raw sockets.  Yes, I have a reason.  No, letting the kernel handle the whole process for me won't work (or at least would make it harder).  I'm doing something kind of out of the ordinary.  Don't worry---it's not for "real work" currently, so I'm not about to derail a major project.

Comment: @BradSemrad: I'm handling TCP by myself currently, though it would be nice if there's a way to eventually hand control off to the kernel . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing TCP youself (working with an "IP" Socket/Layer) will have to handle the TCP Checksums. Any layers below or any checksums, will be handled by the underlying OS.

With the TCP/IP Stack you have (bottom to top order)

Link

Internet <- Socket Here Anything here and below will be handled. Essentially you are saying I am writing my own Transport protocol and it happens to be TCP.

Transport <- TCP Here

Application

Comment: That's no fun.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @yakiv That's why you need to work at the application layer (above TCP)  :). - I know you have a reason for it though so that's why you are using it.